# The range of $\frac{2^x-1}{2^x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to find the range of the function $\frac{2^x-1}{2^x+1}$. If we draw using a graph plotter we can see that the range is $-2<y<2$. To find the upper bound, I tried $\frac{2^x-1}{2^x+1}<\frac{2^x-1}{2^x}=1-(\frac{1}{2})^x$, but I cannot get 2 as the upper bound. Is there any way that we can find the upper and lower bound by simple algebra?

Many thanks. Helps are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{2^x-1}{2^x+1} = 1 - \frac{2}{2^x+1}$ and range of $2^x$ is $(0,\infty)$

Thus range of $ 1 - \frac{2}{2^x+1} $ is $(-1,1)$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{2^x-1}{2^x+1}=\frac{2^x+1-2}{2^x+1}=1-\frac2{2^x+1}$$

$\infty>2^x>0\iff\infty>2^x+1>1\iff0<\dfrac1{2^x+1}<1$

$\iff0>-\dfrac2{2^x+1}>-2\iff1>1-\dfrac2{2^x+1}>-1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = 2^x + 1$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So $y \in (1,+\infty)$ and $y^{-1} \in (0,1)$. Such $$\frac{2^x-1}{2^x+1}  =  (y-2)y^{-1}= -2y^{-1} + 1 = -2(0,1) + 1= (-1,1).$$